# Mongoose 4.1.3 save promise not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I can not seem to have save promise working in mongoose.
I have a Option model :

```
let option = new OptionModel({
  value: 'test',
  vote: 0
});
```

which I try to save :

```
option.save().then(function() {
  console.log('saved')
});
```

is not working, it outputs nothing but

```
option.save(function(){
  console.log('saved');
});
```

is working, outputs 'saved'.
Why?

Comment: save doesn't have support in the promise API (unless they fixed it since). Use `Promise.promsifyAll` with bluebird and then `saveAsync`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It says in the documentation, that the function is returning a Promise http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Comment: You're not checking for errors anywhere.

Comment: @httpete not if an error occured in your promise chain.

Comment: I'm using `.save()` with Promises and it's definitely working for me in Mongoose 4.1.3. As @robertklep and @httpete suggested, it may be getting rejected. Try `option.save().then(function() { console.log('saved') }, console.error.bind(console));`  to double-check that you're not getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your schema able to use promise on every call by adding the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-promised

This provide functions with promise but replace the save() function with saveQ().

```
option.saveQ().then(function() {
   console.log('saved')
});
```

Similarly find() is replaced by findQ().

Answer (score 0):

If your Promise callback is not working it might be related to the mongoose.connection. You can check if everything is correct with

```
 mongoose.connection.on('error', err => console.log(err));
```